# Unable to do paswordless ssh even after following standard procedure

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sshfs

I have two systems named Interface(10.1.1.87) and Client-Interface(10.1.1.91). I want to automatically mount an sshfs share from Client-Interface on Interface on boot.

I am using the command:

```
sshfs mc@10.1.1.91:/opt/lampp/ /media/CIDrive/ -o allow_other
```

But it asks for my password. I tried the following to make it password-less:

1. As root on Interface:

   ```
   # ssh-keygen -t rsa
   # chmod 700 ~/.ssh
   # cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh mc@10.1.1.91 'cat > .ssh/authorized_keys'
   ```
2. On Client-Interface I added to the `sshd_config` file:

   ```
   RSAAuthentication yes
   PubkeyAuthentication yes
   StrictModes no
   ```

and restarted the SSH daemon. Nonetheless, it is still asking for the password:

```
root@JMGDDS-Interface:~# ssh -v mc@10.1.1.91
OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-3ubuntu1, OpenSSL 0.9.8g 19 Oct 2007
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 10.1.1.91 [10.1.1.91] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-3ubuntu1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-3ubuntu1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-3ubuntu1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host '10.1.1.91' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
mc@10.1.1.91's password:
```

The permission for the `.ssh` folder is 700; `.pub` and `authorized_keys` are 600. What could be the possible cause? How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you have access to the ssh logs on `10.1.1.91`, and if so, could you post the relevant parts?

Comment: Why didn't you just use [`ssh_copy_id`](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4830/easiest-way-to-copy-ssh-keys-to-another-machine)? It should take care of all permissions and oddities.

Comment: Sep 20 16:18:47 JMGDDS-ClientInterface sshd[25319]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user mc
Sep 20 16:19:05 JMGDDS-ClientInterface sshd[25461]: Accepted password for mc from 10.1.1.87 port 37662 ssh2
Sep 20 16:19:05 JMGDDS-ClientInterface sshd[25461]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user mc by (uid=0)

Comment: I have tried using ssh-copy-id also but to no avail.

Comment: If all else fails, run the ssh daemon with `ssh -d` or `ssh -dd`. You'll see a lot of logs. If you decide to post them, be careful, there'll be a little private information here and there.

Comment: What distro are you running?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't checked recently but if any directory in the path to .ssh is world writable SSH would refuse to use authorized keys from it.  These permissions could allow other users to fake you .ssh directory.

If the home directory is writable by anyone else it will not be used unless StrictModes is turned off.

Answer (score 1):

Check that in your local machine you have a file `~/.ssh/id_dsa` with mode 600 and that the contents of the local`~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub` are also in the remote `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

I'm saying `id_dsa` because it's one of your private keys according to your logs (you also have an `identity` private key). Maybe you can specify which PrivateKey you want to use in your `~/.ssh/config` under `Host your.server.here`. Alternatively, you may check the same for `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and `~/.ssh/id_rsa` if you have an rsa key pair.

Using `ssh_copy_id -i ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub user@host` (if available) is another way to setup key pairs, that also takes care of permissions etc.

Comment: i executed ssh-keygen -t rsa.

Comment: unchecked the line "IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa" in /etc/ssh/ssh_config. Still no luck

Comment: @Pradipto: you don't need to change `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, return it to it's original state.  Remove the local side files `~/.ssh/id_dsa*` and `~/.ssh/identity` if you do not use them for some other  server. Leave only `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` and try again. If it doesn't work, use the `ssh_copy_id` as described and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions on host 10.1.1.91 of directory `.ssh/`, and file `.ssh/authorized_keys`  Perhaps the sshd on that host doesn't like the permissions on that end.

Comment: drwx------ 2 mc mc 4096 2011-09-20 15:32 .ssh

Comment: -rw------- 1 mc mc 403 2011-09-20 16:14 .ssh/authorized_keys

Answer (score 0):

How did your sshd_conf looks like? Are you sure that "StrictModes no" is not commented?

Comment: StrictModes is set to no.

Comment: Can this be an issue with pam?

Comment: Because there is no error in log after line "Next authentication method: publickey" makes me think that it is a server problem (no response was returned); use LogLevel DEBUG3 on server and watch the /var/log/secure.

Comment: I have replicate your config on a fresh Centos and it is working. This is the config:
Protocol 2
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
StrictModes no
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
UsePAM yes
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS
X11Forwarding yes
Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server

Answer (score 0):

Run the server in debug mode.

On the server, as root:

```
# /etc/init.d/ssh stop
# /usr/sbin/sshd -ddd
```

Now connect with the client, and read the server's debug output. This should give you an indication as to why you can't get in. Correct whatever *that* is.

If you happen to be running RedHat (or possibly Fedora) I ran into a [problem with pam_fprintd not being installed](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=505266).

Answer (score 0):

Too late to answer but I think these two points are very important
Check the permission of your home directory in the server as well. I faced a similar problem and the problem was home directory permission. So two things

1. [Your authorized_keys should be 600](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377009/adding-public-key-to-ssh-authorized-keys-does-not-log-me-in-automatically)
2. [Your home directory should be 755](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37164/ssh-and-home-directory-permissions)

`sshd` by default logs some messages into `/var/log/secure` at least in fedora distro. Check there the reason for why you are refused permission.

Look for this line

`sshd[1234]: Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for file /home/user/.ssh/authorized_key`

`sshd[1234]: Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for file /home/user`