# SSH asking for password after ssh-copy-id

Tags: ssh, password

I created a key on my machine with ssh-keygen. I copied the key to remote machine using ssh-copy-id.

Tried to connect to remote machine but it asked me the password. Both machines are ubuntu (local 11.04, remote 8.04)

### EDIT (Output with extra verbose)

Here is the verbose from ssh:

```
    OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-1ubuntu3, OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/leandro/.ssh/config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.217 [192.168.1.217] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/leandro/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file /home/leandro/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/leandro/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/leandro/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/leandro/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/leandro/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/leandro/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_4.7p1 Debian-8ubuntu1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.7p1 Debian-8ubuntu1 pat OpenSSH_4*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-1ubuntu3
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "192.168.1.217" from file "/home/leandro/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/leandro/.ssh/known_hosts:6
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 132/256
debug2: bits set: 527/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 72:d5:e9:a2:09:46:e5:f2:e9:65:39:56:ba:f8:bc:38
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "192.168.1.217" from file "/home/leandro/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/leandro/.ssh/known_hosts:6
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host '192.168.1.217' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/leandro/.ssh/known_hosts:6
debug2: bits set: 555/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/leandro/.ssh/id_rsa (0x21ef1040)
debug2: key: /home/leandro/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/leandro/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/leandro/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/leandro/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/leandro/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/leandro/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/leandro/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
optimaster@192.168.1.217's password: 

leandro@FiberWork72:~$ cd ~/.ssh/
leandro@FiberWork72:~/.ssh$ ls
config  id_rsa  id_rsa.pub  known_hosts  known_hosts.bkp  known_hosts.old
```

### EDIT:

Ok. I notice something here. I was looking at the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys and realized that in the end of the key it's written this:

```
me@my_computer_name
```

instead of:

```
me@my_computer_ip
```

I don't know if have something to do with it, but...

Comment: Can you double check the permissions on the foreign host?  SSHd can be pretty picky.

Comment: @utopiabound: I don't believe this to be a permissions issue. For one, `ssh-copy-id` takes care of that, and it's one of the best reasons to use it instead of the older manual method. For another, you see `ssh` trying to use the keys instead of skipping them, which means at least the client side perms are correct.

Comment: @Rockskull: The user names are apparently different on both hosts. Did you say `ssh-copy-id myuser@remotehost`, or just `ssh-copy-id remotehost`? Check that a copy of `~/.ssh/id-rsa.pub` on localhost exists in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on remotehost.

Comment: @WarrenYoung the client side perms are correct, yes, but the server side isn't seeing any of the keys as valid, so there's something going on.

Comment: Rockskull, did you remember to provide the correct username?

Comment: Yes, I put the correct user in the format ssh-copy-id user@remote-host

Also tried ssh-copy-id -i /home/me/.ssh/<priv_key_name>

Comment: Does appending additional "verbose" switches provide you with more relevant data? example: `ssh -vvv`

Comment: @Tim I've updated the output with the additional verbose

Comment: @Rockskull the 'me@host' at the end of the file is normal, the hostname varies depending on the distro or openssh build.

Comment: @Rockskull the extra verbose output seems to be giving a clue: `debug3: no such identity: /home/leandro/.ssh/id_dsa`. What is the actual command you are using?

Comment: @Rockskull: Can you also post what you get in `/var/log/secure` and/or `auth.log` when you make this login attempt?

Comment: The readable bit at the end of the line is a comment, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Tim I've created the key with ssh-keygen

Just typed that, no paraphrase, didn't change the default names of the files

Then I copied the key using ssh-copy-id user@remote-host

Also tried with the -i argument pointing the file id_rsa.pub in .ssh folder

Comment: @WarrenYoung `ssh-copy-id` only takes care of setting permissions if it creates the files.  If they already exist it doesn't alter/correct permissions.

Answer (score 3):

This [tag wiki](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/ssh/info) has good information about `ssh` and how to troubleshoot some basic problems.

My first guess would be to check the permissions on `~/.ssh` and ensure it is not writable by any user other than you. You can read more on that [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37164/ssh-and-home-directory-permissions).

Comment: I tried permissions and, as @WarrenYoung commented, the ssh-copy-id takes care of that.

Answer (score 2):

Did you name your key something different than id_rsa, id_dsa or id_ecdsa?

By default, ssh will only try with these key names. If you have chose another one, no panic, you can either specify the key name using -i or specify it once and for all in your ~ssh/config file.

Example with -i (perhaps you need to add the ~/.ssh/ before the key name, I can't recall):

```
ssh -i <your_priv_key_name> myuser@192.168.1.217
```

Example of ~/.ssh/config

```
Host 192.168.1.217
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/<your_priv_key_name>
```

Comment: No I haven't name something different. I know I have this done right because I made the same thing with a ssh tunnel I configured in another machine, and it worked, no password required.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that "myuser" is a valid user on the remote system, the key needs to be placed in that users ~/.ssh/authorized_keys (if using the default configuration).

Check your sshd_config on the remote server to ensure what the authkey file should be, look for the line `AuthorizedKeysFile`.

Comment: Tried that. Didn't work.