# SSH connection freezes after bigger output when inactive for a while

Tags: ssh, arch-linux, openssh

I have a problem with an SSH session freezing after using it again when it was idle for a while.

The problem is that the session doesn't freeze immediately, I can still use it. But as soon as a command sends more data, it freezes before any output arrives, and I have to restart the terminal.

If have read earlier solutions about MTU, but there, the session freezes everytime. Here it only happens after a period of inactivity.

Note that I have set `ServerAliveInterval 120` in .ssh/ssh_config

Any clues about how I can solve this?

Comment: Is there a firewall between the client and server?

Comment: There probably is, though I have no control over it (corporate firewall).

Comment: I think the first bullet in my answer will be helpful. Especially in conjunction with the first few lines of `man ssh_config`.

Comment: Change ~/.ssh/ssh_config to ~/.ssh/config. Make sure the permissions on it are 600.

Comment: Note that my answer (the first) contains the solution as well as some other hints towards troubleshooting ssh :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `~/.ssh/ssh_config` to `~/.ssh/config`. Make sure the permissions on it are 700.

This [discussion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37164/ssh-and-home-directory-permissions/37166#37166) has a lot of good information. You can also follow the tag for `ssh` (just click on /ssh under your question) to go to a [tag wiki](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/ssh/info) for more information and trouble shooting guidance.

Comment: I had named it wrong. After renaming it, I (so far) didn't have any freezes anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Suggestions:

- Try setting the `ServerAliveInterval`, `ServerAliveCountMax`, and `TCPKeepAlive` options on the command line instead of through `ssh_config`, to rule out that there is a problem reading your settings. Perhaps the `ssh_config` should be called just `config` instead?
- Use the verbose flag (more than once) to increase chances of an explanatory error message
- Make sure the `ServerAliveInterval` * `ServerAliveCountMax` is less than the firewall's idle time threshold before tearing down your ssh session (ask your network admin).
- If the server is yours, you could try the `ClientAlive*`-options there.
- Check for version incompatibilities if not OpenSSH on both client+server.

Answer (score 0):

you can set up your client to send the tcp keep alive messages. I know it is under the connection options in putty. Not sure on the command line options but this solved it for me when I was having problems. Though it only did it to me on the win7 machines at school.